# Content-Encoding gzip error when request image

Tags: node.js, http, content-encoding

I have a simple node route for an image. I set the Content-Encoding to gzip

and i get this error in browser

> http://localhost:4000/image net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED 200 (OK)

```
app.get("/image", (req, res) => {
  res.set("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=120, immutable");
  res.set("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "image.jpg"));
});
```

Comment: Looks like you're indicating gzipped content in the header but not actually gzipping the image?

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry That sounds about right